# Deep Clone of code first EF Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-6, clone

I am attempting a Generic Deep Clone Routine for code first Entity Framework entities.

I've cracked it for the standard System property types but am having trouble with Proxy Entities (defined with virtual) i.e.

```
[EntityLookup]
public virtual Person { get; set; }
```

[EntityLookup] is one of my own attributes that helps further define the Association.

If I remove the "virtual" keyword, my routine can update the destination entity property no problem (but I lose the additional EF functionality)
With virtual I get the following error;

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.'
```

I believe it's all to do with EF's Proxy class but I'm not sure how to cast the original entity so I can set it on the destination.
Below are the essentials of the Clone routine for this issue;

```
public static void CloneProperties<T>(T Original, T Destination)    
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = Original.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace == "System" || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)....
        else
        {
                if (Destination.PropertyHasCustomAttribute (propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityLookupAttribute)))
                {
                    var pv = propertyInfo.GetValue(Original, null);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(Destination, pv, null);
                }
         }
    }
}
```

It's the "propertyInfo.SetValue(Destination, pv, null);" that generates the error when the entity is declared virtual.

Any help on getting it to work will be gratefully accepted

Best Regards

Lance

In addition and in a similar vein I am now attempting to clone the child collections in my entity.

I'm iterating over the source property collection and need to add missing records to the destination properties collection

the a.Add(targetEntity); line is giving the following error;

```
"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<FmCosting.Entities.CsJobDetail>.Add(FmCosting.Entities.CsJobDetail)' has some invalid arguments"
```

The relevant code is;

```
                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityChildCollectionAttribute)))
                {
                    var source = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null) as ICollection;
                    var target = propertyInfo.GetValue(dest, null) as ICollection;
                    foreach (dynamic sourceEntity in source)
                    {
                        var found = false;
                        object targetEntity = null;

                        foreach (dynamic tEntity in target)
                        {
                            if (sourceEntity.IdentityGuid == tEntity.IdentityGuid)
                            {
                                found = true;
                                targetEntity = tEntity;
                                continue;
                            }

                        }

                        if (!found)
                        {
                            var t = sourceEntity.GetType();
                            targetEntity = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                        }


                        sourceEntity.CloneMeToProvidedEntity(targetEntity);

                        if (!found)
                        {
                            dynamic a = target;
                            a.Add(targetEntity);
                        }


                    }
                    //propertyInfo.SetValue(Destination, pv, null);
                }
```

Any further help will be gratefully received

Best Regards

Lance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete type for your `destination` object may be different from `T`, for this reason you have to use a `PropertyInfo` of `destination` and not of `original`:

```
public static void CloneProperties<T>(T original, T destination)    
{
    var originalType = original.GetType();
    var destinationType = destination.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] props = originalType.GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace == "System" || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            // ....
        }
        else
        {
            if (destination.PropertyHasCustomAttribute (propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityLookupAttribute)))
            {
                var pv = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                var destinationProperty = destinationType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);
                destinationProperty.SetValue(destination, pv, null);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

#### Note:

Another option is to revert to compile time types, so both objects uses properties of `T` avoiding derived types that may be returned from `GetType()`:

```
public static void CloneProperties<T>(T original, T destination)    
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace == "System" || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            // ....
        }
        else
        {
            if (destination.PropertyHasCustomAttribute (propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityLookupAttribute)))
            {
                var pv = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(destination, pv, null);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Federico.This has helped me enormously

Comment: Hi Federico, I have added a further question, which is in the same scope as the first part regarding the manipulation of a reflected child collection. I'm hoping the answer is as simple for you as the previous question :)

Comment: Glad to help. For the next time, please create another question, is not a best practice to edit an already answered post adding other questions to it. It is usually more useful to create a new one describing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the collection clone working using IList, here is the relevant code if it helps anybody else.

```
if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityChildCollectionAttribute)))
{
    var source = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null) as IList;
    var target = propertyInfo.GetValue(dest, null) as IList;
    foreach (dynamic sourceEntity in source)
    {
        var found = false;
        object targetEntity = null;

        foreach (dynamic tEntity in target)
        {
            if (sourceEntity.IdentityGuid != tEntity.IdentityGuid) continue;
            found = true;
            targetEntity = tEntity;
            break;
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            var b = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            targetEntity = Activator.CreateInstance(b);
        }

        sourceEntity.CloneMeToProvidedEntity(targetEntity);

        if (!found)
        {
            target.Add(targetEntity);
        }
    }
}
```